# Is there a non-reflexive Banach space which is strictly convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I just come up with the fact that a space being [strictly convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space), does not implies it is reflexive (at least I never saw a proof of it).

How can one construct a example of a non-reflexive Banach space which is strictly convex?

Thank you

Comment: One way is to start with a non-reflexive space, then define a norm (1) equivalent to the original norm and (2) strictly convex.  Think about how you would do this.

Comment: Another, more difficult, way is to find a functional in the dual, $f \in X'$, such that does not exists $x \in X$ such that $\langle f, x \rangle = \lVert f \rVert$. In fact, reflexive spaces are characterised by James' theorem (the norm of every functional is achieved in at least one point) and strictly convex spaces are charaterised by the fact that the norm of every functional is achieved at most one point.

Answer (score 1):

*I think it should work*:

One way is to start with these results

> **Lemma.**Let $(K, d)$ be a compact metric space and $\{ t_n \} \subseteq K$ dense and countable. For all $x\in X$ set $\lVert x \rVert = \sqrt{ \lVert x \rVert_{C^0}^2 + \sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}\lvert x(t_n) \rvert^2}$. Then $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{C^0}$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ are equivalent and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is a strictly convex norm.
>
> **Proposition.**Let $X$ be a separable Banach space, $(B_{X'}, \sigma(X',X)) = ( K, d)$ a compact metrizable set. $T : X \to C(K)$ defined by $Tx(f) = \langle f, x \rangle_{X'X}$ is a linear isometry. Hence $X$ has an equivalent strictly convex norm.

Now choose $X$ such that there exists a bounded sequence $\{ x_n \} \subseteq B_X$ that does not admit a subsequence weakly convergent in $B_X$. Hence, by Kakutani's theorem, $X$ can't be reflexive. Such an example could be $X = C([0,1])$. In fact, it is a separable Banach space; $B_{X'}$ is compact in the $\sigma(X',X)$ topology by Banach-Alaouglu theorem. Moreover, $B_{X'}$ is metrizable in $\sigma(X', X)$ because $X$ is separable, but the sequence defined by $x_n(t) := t^n$ is not weakly convergent.

**Notation**. $B_{X'}$ is the unit ball in $X'$; $X'$ is the dual of $X$; $\sigma( X', X )$ is the weak-$\star$ topology of $X'$; $C(K)$ is the space of continuous functions defined on $K$.